# Проблема с прокси requests

Tags: python, requests, proxy

Парсил сайт, он заблокировал мой IP. Купил прокси, пытался работать через него, но выдавало ошибку.

Подскажите, в чём может быть проблема? Потому что через браузер заходит на сайт, а с помощью кода не может.

```
response = requests.get(url='https://www.osd.ru/dtaind.asp?dt=5202', headers={
                'user-agent':  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.5005.148 YaBrowser/22.7.2.899 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36'
            }, proxies={
                'http': '50.114.104.92:45785',
                'https': '50.114.104.92:45785'
            }).content
```

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.osd.ru', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /dtaind.asp?dt=5202 (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required')))
```

Comment: Английским по белому написано же, что этот прокси требует аутентификацию https://stackoverflow.com/a/52051665

Comment: @andreymal Вчистую скопировал тот код, который был по этой ссылке, выдаёт ту же ошибку

Comment: Надо не «вчистую», а прописать правильные логин и пароль, конечно же

Comment: @andreymal Я знаю, что надо заменить на свой логин и на свой пароль. Вылетает та же ошибка